# Why can I not install dconf-tools?

Tags: software-installation, appcenter, apt, dconf

Whenever I try to install `dconf-tool` I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package dconf-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  dconf-cli

E: Package 'dconf-tools' has no installation candidate
```

Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: Does not answer your question, but could be interesting as well: There is currently a "nicer" dconf-editor in development called [Configurator](http://launchpad.net/configurator).

Comment: dconf-tools is a transitional package now IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, my universe source was disabled. To enable it, open Software Centre and navigate to Dconf Editor (you will have to search).

It will say "Available in the Universe repository", and you can click to enable it.

It takes a minute or so, and then you can install from software centre or from terminal.